# Making System.Arraycopy equivalent to a function

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arrays

I need help rewriting a function so that [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) does what the function does.

For example, my code:

```
for( int k = 0; k <= i - 1; k++ ) {
    a[ j + k ] = a[ j + k + 1 ];
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.arraycopy( a, j + 1, a, j, i );
```

But I can't figure out how to do this for:

```
for ( int k = n; k > i; k-- ) {
    a[ j + k ] = a[ j + k - 1 ];
}
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What's that second loop supposed to be doing? Is `j+k` a legal subscript when `j+k > n-1`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify first, since your second loop seems to be a little more complex than necessary. With n=3, i=1, j=2, your loop would transform a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] into a=[1,2,3,4,4,5,7]. In other words, the loop shifts n-i elements one position to the right, starting on index j+i. So, actually you need only two parameters instead of three. (Let's define them to be x=n-i and y=j+i.)

Now, given the following excerpt from the javadoc on `System.arraycopy()`

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination array.

I conclude that `System.arraycopy(a, y, a, y+1, x);` does what you want. Or, if the variables you use are a given, `System.arraycopy(a, j+i, a, j+i+1, n-i);`.

I didn't test it, so let me know if it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 2nd loop intends to move elements i (exclusive) through n (inclusive) one position to the right:

```
System.arraycopy(a, i + 1, a, i + 2, n - i);
```